# Express JS page rendered before async function was executed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, routes

I have a problem with express.js routing. I want to get all restaurants when users open /restaurant/map. Problem is that function gm.geocode is async so page is rendered before that function is executed. How would I get variabile mapsData at the right time, so when page /restaurant/map is loaded? What is the right way to do that?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var gm = require('googlemaps');
var fs=require('fs');
var staticDB=require('./staticDB.js');
var mapsData=[];


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
//not important
});

router.get('/map/', function (req, res, next) {
    var counter=0;
    console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl);
    for (i = 0; i < staticDB.addresses.addresses.length; i++) {
        gm.geocode(staticDB.addresses.addresses[i].street + ", " + staticDB.addresses.addresses[i].city, function (err, data){
            mapsData.push({
                "name": staticDB.restaurants.restaurants[counter].name,
                "location": data.results[0].geometry.location
            });
            counter++;
        }, false);
    }
    res.render('map', {
        title: 'title',
        restaurants: mapsData
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use regular `for` loops to deal with asynchronous flows. There are modules that handle those scenarios for you, like [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async), or even promises. In your case, your code should look like this, using [`async.each`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#each) (I didn't test it):

```
router.get('/map/', function (req, res, next) {
  var counter=0;
  console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl);
  async.each(staticDB.addresses.addresses, function (address, cb) {
    gm.geocode(address.street + ", " + address.city, function (err, data){
        mapsData.push({
            "name": staticDB.restaurants.restaurants[counter].name,
            "location": data.results[0].geometry.location
        });
        counter++;
        cb();
    }, false);
  }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.render('error', { error: err });
    }
    res.render('map', {
      title: 'title',
      restaurants: mapsData
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Is there some other good practices to deal with those async calls (in this example google maps api) in express.js?

Comment: Well, the `async` module is a very good alternative. But you can also use `promises`. Just search on npm.org for _promises_ and you'll see a lot of modules that use this approach. Just don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.